# Python web-scraping with login on button

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests

Unfortunately I'm far from Frontend and previously I was scraping only simple sites with direct links. But here I am faced with some javascript React Modal magic and can't understand how to break through login page.

So, I'm trying to connect to https://megamarket.zakaz.ua/en/. There is a pop-up login window when clicking on "Sign in".

My plan was to make POST request with login options, then use BeautifulSoup to parse.

Something like this:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post('https://megamarket.zakaz.ua/en/login', data = {
        'username': <logn>,
        'password': <pass>}
        )
    data = s.get(...parse link...)
# btfsp on data
```

But I failed in inspecting elements - cant figure out how to make POST request with all this modern visual pop-up elements. I think I need to use Selenium lib.

Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Thanks to @Kurosh, I manged to get correct data for POST request, but somehow getting status 400, 
`{"errors":[{"error_code":4182,"description":"Login or password is incorrect."}]}`

```
import requests
payload={"login": "38063333333", "password": "275699"}
url = "https://stores-api.zakaz.ua/user/login/"
with requests.Session() as s:
    response_op = s.post(url, json=payload)
    print(response_op.status_code)
    print(response_op.text)
```

Data is correct:
[image]

Ok. It's my fault - completley forgot about Headers in Request.
Now everything is fine!

[image]

Comment: go to Network tab in dev console. then login to website and see the POST requests that are about login. You can find a URL in the top use that (it can be different from the one that you are using). and in the end you can find the data parameters that you should give to POST request.

Comment: Indeed! Thank you, Kurosh!

Comment: Your welcome @Oleksii

Comment: Maybe you have ideas where to look if  I'm getting 400, error - wrong ligin/pass, at the same time through web interface with same credentioals all is fine..

Comment: I didn't quite get what you are getting. Do you have problems with login or after that?

Comment: I've updated question above with screens